# Putting Delay in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait

I want to put delay of around **60 seconds** in my code. I have used the following code, to put some delay; but it doesn't behave as expected.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Calling my function after 15 seconds delay.
    }
}, 15000);
```

p.s. : I don't want to use **Thread.sleep()**, as it creates hindrance in normal operation of application.

Comment: why that code is not behaving correctly?

Comment: Please, improve the spelling and punctation in your question.

Comment: why `15000` ???

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya "Calling my function after 15 seconds delay"

Comment: @firegloves this delay function behaves unusual if i you use it more than two or three time .e.g.

Comment: Check your import at the top of the class may be have imported wrong one Handler the import must be `android.os.Handler;`

Comment: and if you want to delay of 60 seconds change  ` }, 15000);`  to  ` }, 60000);`

Comment: @VikasTiwari this is understood thing. one would definitely know the delay time in miliseconds before using it

Comment: @firegloves this delay function behaves unusual if i you use it more than two or three time .e.g.
call this delay function like 3 times and do a different work/function call or even display a message. This handler will never behaves as it shuold be

Comment: it sounds strange, i used more than 3 times but only with the same work

Comment: @waqas you have to mention these things in your question you does not mention anything in your question.

Comment: @VikasTiwari see that commented line in void run().

Answer (score 1):

You can try CountDownTimer.

```
// You can change millisInFuture and countDownInterval according to your need.
long millisInFuture = 60000;
long countDownInterval = 1000;

new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
     @Override
     public void onTick(long l) {
         // Method call according to countDownInterval.
         // For E.g we are taking 1000 so this method call every 1 second.
     }

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
         // When 60 second completed call this method.
         // Do your logic here.
     }
}.start();
```

***Actual thing you want to do like this.***

```
long millisInFuture = 60000;
    long countDownInterval = 1000;
    int counter = 0;

    new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            // Method call according to countDownInterval.
            // For E.g we are taking 1000 so this method call every 1 second.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // When 60 second completed call this method.
            // Do your logic here.
            counter++;
            if (counter == 1) {
                // Call your 1st function
            } else if (counter == 2) {
                // Call your 2nd function
            } else if (counter == 3) {
                // Call your 3rd function
            } else if (counter == 4) {
                // Call your 4th function
            } else if (counter == 5) {
                // Call your 5th function
            }

            if (counter < 5) {
                start();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: you can check yourself by putting code in a for loop or may write again and again for two to three times in order to know the behavior of onFinish()

Comment: @waqas This code is one of my working app it is working code. You said you use this code inside for loop. What you try to do exactly can you please tell me.

Comment: i have five different functions and i want to call each after 1 minute

Comment: Okey. First of all you can not use for loop for this. Now you want to call each function after 1 minute so whenever onFinish() call then you can again call this method and call your function 5 times.

Comment: @waqas see my updated answer the thing you are looking for you can do this way.